Does WordPress maintain revisions for index.html template?
In FSE, all templates except the Index template maintain revisions.


But I cannot see the revisions option for the Index template:

The problem is that many of our clients who are not very familiar with FSE, end up editing the Index template directly and wish to revert to their previous version.
Is there any way to enable this? Thanks!
